# PACT for a JSON array of integers

Tags: java, lambda, pact

Got the following JSON:

```
    {
   "content": [
       7,
       8,
       9,
       10
   ],
   "last": true,
   "total_elements": 9,
   "total_pages": 2,
   "first": false,
   "number_of_elements": 4,
   "size": 5,
   "number": 1,
   "empty": false
}
```

and I would like to create a contract with PACT using the following code:

```
DslPart body = newJsonBody((root) -> {
       root.array("consumer", a ->  a.integerType().integerType().integerType())
               .booleanType("last")
               .numberType("total_elements")
               .numberType("total_pages")
               .booleanType("first")
               .numberType("number_of_elements")
               .numberType("size")
               .numberType("number")
               .booleanType("empty");
   }).build();
```

Although this is working, I really do not like the array contract using a concatenation of integerType.

My question is: is there a better way to indicate an array of X elements, which have to be of type Integer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minArrayLike`.

```
@Test
public void test() {
      DslPart body = newJsonBody((root) ->
              root.minArrayLike("content", 4, PactDslJsonRootValue.integerType(1), 4)
              .booleanType("last")
              .numberType("total_elements")
              .numberType("total_pages")
              .booleanType("first")
              .numberType("number_of_elements")
              .numberType("size")
              .numberType("number")
              .booleanType("empty"))
              .build();

      System.out.println(body.toString());
  }
```

Produces

```
{
  "content": [
    1,
    1,
    1,
    1
  ],
  "number": 100,
  "last": true,
  "size": 100,
  "total_elements": 100,
  "total_pages": 100,
  "number_of_elements": 100,
  "first": true,
  "empty": true
}
```